# How to solve: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/soap/SOAPFaultException

Tags: java, apache, servletexception

I met " javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/soap/SOAPFaultException" exception when I click the button in my jsp webpage.

It worked fine when I ran it in Eclipse. so I published it to webapps and started the apache web service in system tray. 
I accessed web address that I configured, JSP page works fine but when I click the button in my jsp web page, Error came out.

The following is the Root cause of error message.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/soap/SOAPFaultException
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:213)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/soap/SOAPFaultException
oss_api.oss.Search_the_license(oss.java:105)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:134)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1928)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1771)
oss_api.oss.Search_the_license(oss.java:105)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:134)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above exception clearly states that the dependency library has not be included can you list down all the jar being used by your project

Most probably the jar which is missing from your project is [jax-ws.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api/2.1)

Comment: Thank you, NIKET BHANDARY!!

Comment: Thank you, you just save me